# When data is queried from database

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net

According to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb552415.aspx) a LINQ query is not executed before iterated over in a foreach loop.

But when I try the following:

```
namespace MCSD487_AdoConnection
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataSet.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            FillDataSet(dataSet);

            DataTable folders = dataSet.Tables["Folder"];

            IEnumerable<DataRow> folderQuery = folders.AsEnumerable();

            IEnumerable<DataRow> aFolders = folderQuery.Where(f => f.Field<string>("Name")[0].ToString().ToLower() == "a");

            // this is where I thought the SQL execution whould happen
            foreach (DataRow row in aFolders)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} was created on {1}", row.Field<string>("Name"), row.Field<DateTime>("DateTime"));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        internal static void FillDataSet(DataSet dataSet)
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;

                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DateTime, Name FROM Folder", connectionString);

                // Add table mappings.
                dataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Folder");
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

                // Fill the DataSet.
                // This it where the actual SQL executes
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SQL exception occurred: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I look at my SQL Server Profiler, I can see that the actual SQL call is performed when I call the `dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)` in the FillDataSet method and not when iterating through rows.

My question is: How do I make LINQ perform the SQL execution on only the names starting with 'a' (without specifying that in the SQL commandText in the FillDataSet method)?

EDIT 2013-07-07 23:44:
I ended with the following solution, based on Evan Harpers answer:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace MCSD487_AdoConnection
{
    [Table(Name = "Folder")]
    public class Folder
    {
        private int _Id;
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Storage = "_Id")]
        public int Id
        {
            get { return _Id; }
            set { _Id = value; }
        }

        private DateTime _DateTime;
        [Column(Storage = "_DateTime")]
        public DateTime DateTime
        {
            get { return _DateTime; }
            set { _DateTime = value; }
        }

        private string _Name;
        [Column(Storage = "_Name")]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set { _Name = value; }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataContext db = new DataContext(new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=OLF\OLF;Initial Catalog=DirStructure;Integrated Security=True"));

            Table<Folder> folders = db.GetTable<Folder>();

            IQueryable<Folder> folderQuery = from folder in folders
                                             where folder.Name[0].ToString().ToLower() == "a"
                                             select folder;

            foreach (Folder folder in folderQuery)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} was created on {1}", folder.Name, folder.DateTime);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for guiding me in the right direction.

Comment: If you were querying a LINQ-enabled data-source (EF, LINq-to-SQL, etc), ***and*** if you were using `IQueryable<T>` rather than `IEnumerable<T>` - *then* it might do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly the expected behavior. You are using ADO.NET to get the data into a DataTable, and then querying against the DataTable – not the underlying database – in line with ADO.NET's [disconnected architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27y4ybxw.aspx).

If you want to see your LINQ queries turned into optimized database calls just-in-time, use something like [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

With DataSet you can'T do it. The only way is to fill the DataSet/Table adapter with the limited results (the starts with stuff have to be written in SQL).